# getting an error snapshot.data is not a function

Tags: html, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

**Tech stack:** React, Firebase, Next.js

My website runs like this; when a user registers, a document (in 'User' collection), a 'vote' subcollection containing 2 documents, is created. And right after that user registers, the website should call 2 functions: `getUserInfo()` and `getUserVotes` from `useEffect()`, which basically read all the documents which was created earlier.

Now. The problem is, when a user first registered, and this `getUserVotes` is called, there was an error saying threadSnap.data is not a function even though threadSnap is supposed to be document snapshot not querySnapshot (which is why this should work properly). But after refreshing a page, this error just disappears.

```
const getUserVotes = async (user) => {
    const uid = user.uid;
    if (user) {
      Promise.allSettled([
        getDoc(doc(db, "users", uid, "votes", "threads")),
        getDoc(doc(db, "users", uid, "votes", "replies"))
      ]).then(([threadSnap, replySnap]) => {
        setUserVotes({
          threads: threadSnap.data(),
          replies: replySnap.data()
        })
      })
    }
  }
```

At first, I tried calling `getDoc` two times like this

```
threadSnap = await getDoc(doc(db, "users", uid, "votes", "threads")),
replySnap = await getDoc(doc(db, "users", uid, "votes", "replies"))
setUserVotes({
  threads: threadSnap.data(),
  replies: replySnap.data()
})
```

But it seems like JS calls `setUserVotes` evenn before two promises complete. Then, I use `Promise.all` on two `getDoc` but then the state both becomes *undefined* (for some reason). Finally, I land on `Promise.allSettled` which seems to work normally except when the user registers for the first time that the error ***threadSnap.data** is not a function*. I expect my program to wait for two `getDoc` to resolve before setting my state through `setUserVotes`. Can you guys help?

Comment: by the way, because I don't really find anything wrong with the code (it works fine after first write), one possible issue is that Firebase takes too much time to write new subcollection and doc, which cause the `getDoc` to return undefined